# Android - homescreen appwidget transparency

Tags: android, android-widget, transparency

I have an application that publishes a homescreen widget. The widget has portions that are transparent. I have recently updated to API 10 and latest ADT (10), and now my Appwidget has lost it's transparency. Has anyone encountered this and have you found a fix?

My widget is a PNG-24 with transparency info, it is 100x100 pixels - might that be the issue? It has been working well previously. I am testing on Android 2.2 device (HTC Incredible) as well as on emulator 2.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh! I had the color changed in the layout wrapping the widget element from #0000 to #000000 which is obviously not transparent.